# where is the pandas documentation code in git so we can run it in ipython/jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas

Like the pandas cookbook code is in git and downloadable and changeable using ipython. Can we do the same with the pandas documentation code ? I could not find the repo for it. Copy and pasting it and then running it will be too tedious hence was wondering if there is a repo for it?

Comment: Pandas documentation not necessarily has code for all example and it has more of argument explanation than executable example. So, I think it wont make much of meaning

Comment: The pandas documentation is in the main pandas repo (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/) under `doc/source`. But you will have to copy paste from there as well. What do you exactly want to obtain?